# Google Page Speed and Blessed CSS

Tags: google-pagespeed

Currently I'm working on the website www.gassan.com

When I check the pagespeed of this website I get the following message:

Optimise the CSS for the next URL's:
https://www.gassan.com/static/css/style.blessed.css
https://www.gassan.com/…yle.blessed-blessed1.css?z=1429783661837

But this CSS is already optimised? I don't get it. Google always gives me problems :(

Answer (score 0):

It probably complains about the query string after .css. This is causing browsers to not being able to cache it properly. If the z=1429783661837 changes, the browser would then have to load a new copy. But it's probably what you want I guess? It's a bad idea to change ?z on all requests, but if a timeout goes out or it can detect a file change somehow, it's fine.

Remember, Page Speed is there to help you, it will not always be right.